# Convert Existing String date to 'm/j/Y' in PHP Core

Tags: php, magento, cakephp, magento-1.7, cakephp-2.1

I have existing date as `2000-06-22` and i want to convert it as `06/22/2000` format
Any PHP technology can work. I m working this in magento.
How ? Any Solutions ? 
thanks in advance. !!

Comment: You can use strtotime()

Comment: i have used but Magento date format is not setting with that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date('m/j/Y', strtotime('2000-06-22'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$dt_str = '2000-06-22';
$date   = new Datetime($dt_str);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: Try just copy the code and execute, because it works perfectly for me

Comment: Yes, Sorry, it executed in core in simple php page
But i am editing Magento's phtml page..
Magento shows Invalid Date format !!